# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error, but program is working fine

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

My objective is to print the non comment lines of a file to the screen or to a output file, however specified. My code is working fine in both cases (i.e. I am getting the desired output) However, when I print the lines to the screen, it works fine and after printing everything out, it says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

**Here is my code:**

```
/* Assignment 1 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXS 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *op;
  char line[MAXS] = {0};
  int max_x, max_y, num_pt, rand_inst;
  int ch;
  int inputfile = 0, outputfile = 0;
  int i;


  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if (strcmp (argv[i], "-i") == 0)
    inputfile = i+1;
      if (strcmp (argv[i], "-o") == 0)
    outputfile = i+1;
    }
  if (inputfile == 0)
    {
      /* invalid command line options */
      printf("\nIncorrect command-line...\n");
      printf("> %s [-i inputfile [-o outputfile]]\n\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
    }

  fp = fopen(argv[inputfile], "r");
  if (fp == 0)
    {
      printf("\nCould not find %s\n", argv[inputfile]);
      exit(0);
    }
 /* while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)) */

 /* This part is where I get the error but I get the desired output */
  if (outputfile == 0)
    {
      while (fgets (line, MAXS, fp) != NULL) 
        {         
          char *p = line;
          size_t len = strlen (line);

          while (len > 0 && (line[len-1] == '\n' || line[len-1] == '\r'))
                line[--len] = 0;    /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */


          while (isspace (*p))  /*  advance to first non-whitespace  */
                p++;

          /* skip lines beginning with '#' or blank lines  */
          if (*p == '#' || !*p)
                continue;

          printf("%s\n", line);

        }
    }
  else
    {
      op = fopen(argv[outputfile], "w");
      while (fgets (line, MAXS, fp) != NULL) 
        {
          char *p = line;

          size_t len = strlen (line);

          while (len > 0 && (line[len-1] == '\n' || line[len-1] == '\r'))
                line[--len] = 0;    /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */


          while (isspace (*p))  /*  advance to first non-whitespace  */
                p++;

          /* skip lines beginning with '#' or blank lines  */
          if (*p == '#' || !*p)
                continue;

          fprintf(op, "%s\n", line);

        }
    }
  fclose(op);

  return 0;
}
```

**Here is the output which gives me segmentation fault:**

> 100   100
>
> 10
>
> 0 0
>
> 0 90
>
> 70    100
>
> 100   50
>
> 30    30
>
> 30    70
>
> 70    70
>
> 70    30
>
> 50    50
>
> 45    0
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>
> The above however, is the desired output minus the Segmentation fault error

***I know Segmentation fault is something to do with reading/writing illegal memory location, but I cant quite figure out why the program is giving me the error provided I have no compilation errors and I am getting the desired output***

**Language: c99 ; Compiler: gcc**

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you immediately which line is causing the seg fault (and much more). My guess is this line: `if (*p == '#' || !*p)`. There are no checks to verify that `p` is still a valid pointer (ie, hasn't run off the end of the `line` buffer).

Comment: "program is working fine" - the preamble to that statement would suggest that not to be the case.  If it were me, I'd start by turning up your warning levels to pedantic heights, then *fixing* (not hiding) whatever is flagged. Ex: what value for `op` do you expect to be passing for `fclose(op);` in the case where the `if` and not the `else` branch of your suspicious section is taken (such as the case where you do *not* specify an output file)? The presented indentation doesn't make it easy to see that `fclose(op);` is in the wrong place. It should be *inside* the closing `else` brace.

Comment: @WhozCraig You were right, I have put my `fclose(op)` within the `else statement` and I didnt receive the error.

Comment: Note that you should not have two vast repeats of code as shown.  You should either open the file (`op = fopen(…);`) or use `stdout` (`op = stdout;`) and then use the more general code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seg fault is being caused by your last line `fclose(op)`.  I suspect `op` is `NULL` or an invalid memory location (i.e. garbage), which is causing the seg fault.

In addition to sticking the `fclose` within the `else` statement (as noted in the comments)...I'd also initialize those file pointers.

Comment: There's no need to initialize the file pointers in their declarations as long as valid values are assigned to them before their values are used.  In particular, there's no reason to suppose that initializing them would have prevented the OP's segfault, or if it did, that the resulting alternative behavior would have been better.